# Running client sided convars on the server in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration, source-engine

Is there a way to run client sided convars server side?

I have tried `sv_accelerate_use_weapon_speed 0`, but that's a client-sided convar, so it doesn't work on the server.

Is there any way to run client-sided convars sent by the server? I'm putting this into my `server.cfg`.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit more? Are you running an offline CS:GO server or a remote server that you own?

Comment: I own the entire server, so I'm assuming its the remote server.

Comment: Which `server.cfg` did you edit, the one that you had on your computer or the `server.cfg` of the server on which you play? When you join a game, the cfg of the server is executed so you might wanna try that.

Comment: Im editing my `csgo/cfg/server.cfg`. This is in pterodactyl.

Comment: When you edit your local `csgo/cfg/server.cfg`, it set the configuration for your local server. You will have to change the file that is on your remote server for the changes to be applied to the CS:GO server that your remote server hosts.